# Property is null after parseJSON in success callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

As part of an AJAX call I have an attribute "success" which looks like this:

```
success: function(msg) {
          console.log( msg );
          var obj = $.parseJSON( msg );

          if (obj.code=="1")
          {
            ...
          }
}
```

As you can see I'm expecting a JSON string and indeed there is one being returned from the server which looks like this: `{"code":"1","message":"1","name":"Alan"}`

That JSON string is what gets displayed in FireBug under the NET/Response tab. Which is fine. You can see I'm using parseJSON(...) to get a handle on object.  But when the conditional statement executes, I'm being told that obj is NULL.  That can't be good!  I don't know what's going on there.

You will notice that I print to the console the msg variable.  This is what is looks like:

> Object { code="1", message="1", name="Alan"}

The only difference I see between the returned JSON string and what gets printed to the console is the fact that we have the colons being replaced with equals symbol.  I don't know if that's significant or not??

Anybody out there come across this before?  PLease advise.

Alan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your console's log indicates that msg has already been parsed from json to an object.  Do not call `$.parseJSON` just use msg as the object.
Additionally if you're expecting a json response from your request set the $.ajax `dataType` parameter to `json` to ensure that your json is parsed to an object for you.

Comment: Hey, that was it. I thought I still had to use the parseJSON(...) call even though I had set the dataType to json. Looks like I was wrong.  Thanks for the guidance.